# Retornar valor processado no Javascript para o managed bean

Tags: javascript, java, jsf, primefaces, dom

Retornar valor processado no Javascript para o managed bean é possível?
O que é diferente nesse processo é que executo o método JS no bean, assim:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("getResult()");
```

Answer (score 0):

É possível, indiretamente, utilizando o `p:remoteCommand`.

Onde um a chamada JavaScript pode executar métodos no *Bean*.

Veja um exemplo em: [remoteCommand Primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml).